# Is there any specific significance attached with green colored Hanuman-murtis?

Tags: identification-request, hanuman, symbolism, color

Found this photo online, and this is unlike any color depiction of Hanuman, I have seen yet. Mostly, red or orange depictions, I have come across.

[image]

Is this depiction a canonical one? Or based on any local, sthala puranas or other allied scriptures?

Where is this particular idol found? Any specific temple?

**Is a green-complexioned form of God Hanuman mentioned in any scripture?**

What is the significance and symbolism behind this form particular form of the lord, if any?

Comment: have seen that description mostly in South india

Comment: Yes, that's what I have heard @AdityaDwivedi. However, finding a scriptural reference would be great, don't you think?!